# Regex Match more than 4 characters

Tags: c#, regex

I got a problem with the Regex Match with more than 4 characters. I've tried with 4 characters and it returns *kind of true*. However, for more than 4 characters, it returns *kind of false*. Please let me know what happened there.

> ```
>     public static string CardRegex =
>         @"^(?:(?<VisaDebit>4744)|
>         (?<Discover>6011)|
>         (?<Amex>3[47]\d{2}))([ -]?)(?(DinersClub)(?:\d{6}\1\d{4})|(?(Amex)(?:\d{6}\1\d{5})|(?:\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4})))$";
> ```

```
    public static CreditCardTypeType? GetCardTypeFromNumber(string cardNum)
    {
        var cardTest = new Regex(CardRegex);

        var gc = cardTest.Match(cardNum).Groups;

        if (gc[CreditCardTypeType.VisaDebit.ToString()].Success)
            return CreditCardTypeType.VisaDebit;
        if (gc[CreditCardTypeType.Discover.ToString()].Success)
            return CreditCardTypeType.Discover;
        return null;
    }
```

Input: 4744721015347572

```
(?<VisaDebit>4744) ==> return VisaDebit
(?<VisaDebit>4744**7**) ==> return null
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is kind of unclear. Your only sample string is `4744721015347572`, and your regex [shows a match (if compiled with IgnoreWhitespace flag)](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cVisaDebit%3e4744%29%7c%0d%0a++++++++%28%3f%3cDiscover%3e6011%29%7c%0d%0a++++++++%28%3f%3cAmex%3e3%5b47%5d%5cd%7b2%7d%29%29%28%5b+-%5d%3f%29%28%3f%28DinersClub%29%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b6%7d%5c1%5cd%7b4%7d%29%7c%28%3f%28Amex%29%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b6%7d%5c1%5cd%7b5%7d%29%7c%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b4%7d%5c1%5cd%7b4%7d%5c1%5cd%7b4%7d%29%29%29%24&i=4744721015347572&o=x) with `4744` in *VisaDebit* group.Is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

`^` asserts the current position at beginning of a string

`$` asserts the current position at the end of the string

Since these are outside capture groups, every card number entered must match, which is of course intentional. However, a 5 digit number matches nothing.

In the case of `(?:(?<VisaDebit>4744)`, you're searching for this 4 digit number. Along with the assertions described above, you're matching this 4 digit number alone which is why `47447` doesn't match, it basically exceeds where you've asserted the end of the string, unless one of your alternations match.

---

You have a DinersClub condition `(?(DinersClub)` without a like-named group. I don't know if this is intentional.

---

Something is wrong in your matching pattern to begin with. This is your regex, unchanged. I've only formatted it so you can see your branching.

```
^
(?:
  (?<VisaDebit>4744)
|
  (?<Discover>6011)
|
  (?<Amex>3[47]\d{2})
)
([ -]?)
(?(DinersClub)                 # as described above, you have no DinersClub Group
  (?:\d{6}\1\d{4})
|
  (?(Amex)
    (?:\d{6}\1\d{5})           # this is a problem similar to the analasys below
  |
    (?:\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4})    # this is probably a problem
  )
)$
```

Problem subpattern analasys

```
\d{4}  # this is saying any 4 digits
\1     # this is a repetition of CG 1. Whatever it matched
         # not any 4 digits, but 4744
\d{4}  # any 4 digits
\1     # explained above
\d{4}  # any 4 digits
```

---

You're probably never matching the Visa conditional with the number that can match. It's trying Visa, realizing it doesn't match, backtracking, skipping Discover and trying AmEx and following through.

**Edit:** I see, I see. You may not have realized that Named Groups are still numbered.